# spyder ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, spyder, modulenotfounderror

This error is coming when i am trying to import Sklearn in Spyder IDE. But it is running smoothly on python 3.11 terminal if i am trying to install in by pip install Sklearn its showing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu0Fr.png)

on Spyder ide its showing :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4a6P.png)
This on importing sklearn.
on python3.11 it is not giving any error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DHiK.png)

how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Probably you have more than one Python interpreter on your system and Spyder is not using the one where you installed sklearn. Check Spyder's settings.